# JPA unidirectional many to many and join table

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In JPA/Spring Data, I want to add an object (DsConfig) to a DsConfig list of the CampaignStructure object. 
This list has a uni-directional many-to-many association

```
@Service
public class CampaignConfigurationService {


    @Transactional
    public void saveCampaignConfiguration(CampaignConfigurationModel campaignConfigurationModel){

    [...]

        CampaignStructure campaignStructure=campaignStructureService.findOne(campaignStructureId);

    [...]


        DsConfig dsConfig=new DsConfig();
        dsConfig.setDataSource(dataSourceModel.getDatasource());
        dsConfig.setSource(sourceSelected);
        dsConfig.setLocation(dataSourceModel.getUrlLocation());

        // dsConfig=dsConfigService.save(dsConfig);

        campaignStructure.getDsConfigs().add(dsConfig);

    [...]

        campaignStructureService.save(campaignStructure);

    [...]
```

CampaignStructure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CAMPAIGN_STRUCTURE")
public class CampaignStructure implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="CAMPAIGN_STRUCTURE_ID")
    private int campaignStructureId;

    private String url;

    //uni-directional many-to-one association to Campaign
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CAMPAIGN_ID")
    private Campaign campaign;

    //uni-directional many-to-one association to UseCase
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USE_CASE_ID")
    private UseCase useCase;

    //uni-directional many-to-many association to DsConfig
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="CAMPAIGN_STRUCTURE_DS_CONFIG"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="CAMPAIGN_STRUCTURE_ID")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="DS_CONFIG_ID")
            }
        )
    private List<DsConfig> dsConfigs;

    [...]
```

DsConfig:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DS_CONFIG")
@NamedQuery(name="DsConfig.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM DsConfig d")
public class DsConfig implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="DS_CONFIG_ID")
    private int dsConfigId;

    @Column(name="DATA_IMPORT")
    private String dataImport;

    private String location;

    //uni-directional many-to-one association to DataSource
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DATA_SOURCE_ID")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    //uni-directional many-to-many association to DsData
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="DS_CONFIG_DS_DATA"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="DS_CONFIG_ID")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="DS_DATA_ID")
            }
        )
    private List<DsData> dsData;

    //uni-directional many-to-one association to Source
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="SOURCE_ID")
    private Source source;
```

When I run the saveCampaignConfiguration method I get this error:

```
16:46:52,539 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/MyProject].[appServlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.myorg.entity.DsConfig with id 0
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration$Ejb3EntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(Ejb3Configuration.java:154) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:210) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
```

If I save the dsConfig object before to add to the list I get this other error. I think the problem is again for the id=0.

```
16:49:25,837 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/MyProject].[appServlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`campaign_structure_ds_config`, CONSTRAINT `fk_CAMPAIGN_STRUCTURE_DS_CONFIG_DS_CONFIG1` FOREIGN KEY (`DS_CONFIG_ID`) REFERENCES `ds_config` (`DS_CONFIG_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON U)
```

Thanks.

***EDIT***


Added

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

to DsConfig entity definition;

now it works if I save the DsConfig before to save CampaignStructure.